# pass values from select form to mysql DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have one simple problem with mysql-db. I want to pass 3 values in one column of my db that is called `DateOfBirth`.

I have made 2 selectors, day and month, and one text are for year (`yer`).

I want to combine these values to php variables and pass it to mysql column that is VARCHAR. 
Dose any one has solution for this?

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))


{
    $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['day'.'month'.'yer']);


    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO userprofile(gender,dateofbirth) VALUES('$dob')"))
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
<body>
<center>
    <div id="login-form">

        <form method="post">
            <table align="center" width="30%" border="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="day">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                            <option value="13">13</option>
                            <option value="14">15</option>
                            <option value="16">16</option>
                            <option value="17">17</option>
                            <option value="18">18</option>
                            <option value="19">19</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="21">21</option>
                            <option value="22">22</option>
                            <option value="23">23</option>
                            <option value="24">24</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="26">26</option>
                            <option value="27">27</option>
                            <option value="28">28</option>
                            <option value="29">29</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                            <option value="31">31</option>
                        </select>


                        <select name="month">
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">February</option>
                            <option value="3">March</option>
                            <option value="4">April</option>
                            <option value="5">May</option>
                            <option value="6">June</option>
                            <option value="7">July</option>
                            <option value="8">August</option>
                            <option value="9">September</option>
                            <option value="10">October</option>
                            <option value="11">November</option>
                            <option value="12">December</option>

                        </select>
                        <input class="yer" type="text" name="yer" placeholder="yer" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                    <td><button type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Me Up</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="index.php">Sign In Here</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `gender` doing in your insert query???

Comment: you're telling the DB to expect two fields of data (`gender,dateofbirth`) and then providing only one bit of data (dob). Exactly what do you think should happen in this case?

Comment: you have 2 columns but 1 value; syntax error. and your `else` is NOT helping you.

Comment: Your column should be a `date` column, not `varchar`.

Comment: `dbconnect.php` <= Pandora's box as are `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`. and that isn't how `$_POST` works `$_POST['day'.'month'.'yer']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
$dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['day'.'month'.'yer']);
```

To

```
$y = $_POST['yer'];
$m = $_POST['month'];
$d = $_POST['day'];
$dob = strtotime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$a);
```

EDIT: If you're inserting into the gender row, you need to supply a value for gender, otherwise it's going to either throw an error or go ahead with the query inserting dob into the gender row and then throw an error

Comment: why should they? you missed something

Comment: You don't have to escape strtotime and can be easily translated into whatever they want when retrieving from db without the extra step of converting it time since it's now already done before inserting into db.